# How do I get the forecolor of a cell in BeforeCheckNode event

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtratreelist

I need to set CanCheck as true or false depending on ForeColor of Node in BeforeCheckNode  event. How can I get the ForeColor of e.Node in BeforeCheckNode event ?

```
private void _tree_BeforeCheckNode(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.CheckNodeEventArgs e)
    {

        int index = _tree.GetNodeIndex(e.Node);
        RowInfo ri = _tree.ViewInfo.RowsInfo.Rows[index] as RowInfo;
        CellInfo cell = (CellInfo)ri.Cells[0];
        if (cell.PaintAppearance.ForeColor == Color.LightGray)
            e.CanCheck = false;
    }
```

But here index is relative to parent. So if I have multiple parent with child nodes, RowInfo comes wrong. And if I use visible index, it won't work for RowInfo as it goes out of range.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if ((_tree.ViewInfo.RowsInfo[e.Node].Cells[0] as CellInfo).PaintAppearance.ForeColor == Color.LightGray)
            e.CanCheck = false;
```

Solved my problem.